# How to add manual option in dynamic appending select options?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my javascript code :

```
$('#select_list_div').empty();

allRecords.push(arrayRec[i]);
allRecords.forEach( function(s) {                               
    $('#select_list_div').append('<option value="' + s.serial_no + '">' + s.serial_no + '.' + s.title + '</option>');   
});
```

In this code all data from `arrayRec` is getting added in `allRecords`. But In this I want to add one option manually, for example :

```
'<option value="na">Select this</option>'
```

How can I add this in my JavaScript code ?

Comment: specify manually.. user input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
$('#select_list_div').empty();

$('#select_list_div').append('<option value="na">Select this</option>');

allRecords.push(arrayRec[i]);

allRecords.forEach( function(s) {                               
    $('#select_list_div').append('<option value="' + s.serial_no + '">' + s.serial_no + '.' + s.title + '</option>');   
});
```

Or using **[prependTo()](http://api.jquery.com/prependto/)**

```
$("<option value="na">Select this</option>").prependTo("#select_list_div");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you just need to prepend another option, so put this code after your `forEach`:

```
$('#select_list_div').prepend($("<option />", {
    value: 'na',
    text: 'Select this'
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line after you make your element empty.

```
$('#select_list_div').append('<option value="na">Select this</option>');
```